# JQuery - Form Change Detection "before" the form unload in Ajax

Tags: jquery, events, single-page-application

I am trying to implement [SPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507641.aspx) in one of my web application. Due to this, I never leave the main page (*window.onbeforeunload will not get fired*).

Here is simple DOM structure

```
<html>
<head> include jquery and other js css stuff here </head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">Here i do magic to generate a top menu bar</div>
    <div id="content">
      This is the main content area where all the pages get loaded.
    </div>
</body>
```

Every menu click on menubar at the top of the page simply gets a new page content refreshed in a "content" div via `$.ajax()`.

### This is what I want to achive

Say,

1. User opened one page having form elements on it.
2. User went ahead and typed / selected some stuff there.
3. Now user clicked on some other menu item before saving the form which is already loaded.

Can I capture this event and warn user about potentially unsaved data? If yes, how?

I tried to look at [Destroyed event](http://jupiterjs.com/news/element-destroyed-a-jquery-special-event). But destroyed event gets called *after* the element (e.g. form) is removed. I want to capture the event ***before*** and possibly, stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You could, conceivably, set a variable, or `data-*` attribute, when a form field is focused:

```
$('#formID input').focus(
     function(){
         $(this).closest('form').attr('data-inprogress','true');
         /* or:
         var formInProgress = true;
         */
     });

$('form').submit(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('data-inprogress','false');
        /* or:
        formInProgress = false;
        */
    });
```

And then, on clicking on an element that would trigger a page-change or removal of the `form` itself, check for the attribute or variable and, if it exists, confirm with the user that they want to discard the form:

```
$('.pageChangeElements').click(
    function(){
        if ($('#formID').attr('data-inprogress') == 'true'){
            var c = confirm("Do you really want to discard the form?");

            if (c) {
                // continue
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demonstration of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7TjmR/1/)

Comment: Good answer David.. Only issue that I face here is, now I must remember to add this check anywhere and everywhere i have possibility to click a link / button which leads to leaving the page with "potential" changed data in it..

Comment: Well you could, easily enough make this a function, and simply tether the check to any element that could conceivably cause a page-change. Though it's somewhat more difficult than I'd like it to be.